# Advantages of .NET 3.5 vs 2.0, for customers

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-2.0, .net-framework-version

Did you ever have to persuade your customers that migrating your ASP.NET web forms application from 2.0 to 3.5 is necessary?

Why customers should install a new framework? (and sometimes a new operating system - *there are a lot of Windows 2000 machines out there although support for it ended in 2010*).

**Which advantages for them?**

- Security?
- Performances?
- Costs?

Is the only reason that 2.0 is **old**?

Any link is appreciated.

PS:
*Please don't answer that 3.5 has LINQ, it's an advantage for developers not customers*

Comment: I disagree that LINQ is an advantage only for developers. It allows you to create shorter code, which normally means fewer possible bugs and faster development, which are both advantages for your customers.

Comment: Are you talking about versions of ASP.NET or .NET in general?

Comment: Why move to 3.5 as opposed to 4.0? You already drop support for Windows 2000 with migrating to 3.5. 4.0 introduces an entirely new CLR, with several performance improvements. It seems silly to go from current-2 to current-1 without a particularly good reason.

Comment: @Code Gray so for customers moving to 4.0 would mean more sensible advantages?

Comment: @onof: That's not necessarily my point. My comment doesn't specifically answer your question about advantages to upgrading (or I'd have posted it as an answer). I'm simply wondering why you're contemplating upgrading from 2.0 to 3.5, instead of 2.0 all the way to 4.0. Yeah, there's some performance improvements that come with the new CLR, but not substantial enough that I categorically recommend an upgrade. I just think going through the trouble of upgrading, and not jumping out to the latest version is a mistake.

Comment: @Code Gray I absolutely agree, but unfortunately i face with some admins unhappy to upgrade their machines. I know the great advantages for developers to move from 2.0 to 3.5 or 4, but i have difficulty in find points to convince some customers. And some admins did not yet "validated" the framework 4.0 (I'm not kidding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage here is indirectly for the customer, by (hopefully) allowing you to write code faster/shorter and therefore fewer bugs and more deadlines hit.

There may also be small performance increases with the newer iterations of the franmework.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, .NET 3.5 is still using .NET 2.0 as its base, just several add-on.

For old applications, deploying .NET 3.5 have no use. You will only required to install a specific version of the .NET Framework if you're application was created for that.

Anyway, LINQ and WCF are the great add-ons in Framework 3.5 that provide better performance and interoperability. ;)